# Does Noel ever comment that Frasier looks like Captain Bateson?

Tags: character, star-trek, frasier

In the series *Frasier*, [Noel Shempsky](http://frasier.wikia.com/wiki/Noel_Shempsky) is a huge *Star Trek* fan.  Now, the character of *Frasier* character is played by Kelsey Grammer, who also played [Captain Bateson](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Morgan_Bateson) in *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episode ['Cause and Effect'](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cause_and_Effect_(episode)):

[image: Captain Bateson]

As I've mentioned above, these two characters are played by the same actor.  Although in *Frasier* Dr Crane isn't an actor (and isn't playing Kelsey Grammer), surely Noel would still see a huge resemblance.

My question is then: **does Noel ever comment that Dr Crane looks a lot like Captain Bateson?**

Comment: TIL That Frasier ran from 1993 to 2004. I could have sworn it was much older.

Comment: Maybe Noel just wasn't a fan of TNG? I mean, he didn't recognize Patrick Stewart or Brent Spiner's characters as looking similar either.

Comment: @cde and here I was thinking Noel was a fan of Star Trek!

Comment: It's generally assumed that films and TV series take place in a universe where the actors' counterparts don't exist (with some rare exceptions). For example nobody in the Terminator films comments on how the Terminator looks a lot like Arnold Schwarzenegger. Or perhaps Frasier doesn't actually look like Kelsey Grammer, the role is just played by him, just like [King Lear](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2049483) didn't actually look like Ian McKellen. However you want to look at it.

Comment: @Moyli There is a distinct difference here, however. There is a character, in the subsequent show, referencing the existence of the previous show.

Comment: @user001 I don't understand what you're trying to say. I didn't say the *show* doesn't exist, I'm saying the *actors* don't (i.e. Bateson was played by someone else).

Comment: There was a cool throwback in Third Rock when William Shatner and John Lithgow have a little scene together. Lithgow: How was your flight?
Shatner: Awful! I looked out the window and thought I saw a horrible monster on the wing of the plane.
Lithgow: Really?? That happened to me too! Both actors played the same role in The Twilight Zone, of a passenger on an airplane that saw a gremlin tearing the wing apart. Shatner played the role on the TV show, Lithgow in the movie.

Comment: They did this on Scrubs in an episode where J.D. tries to get the janitor to admit that he played the cop on the subway in The Fugitive (they were, in fact, played by the same actor). So the question has precedent.

Comment: Imagine if he'd met Rebecca Howe.

Comment: @cde we don't have any reason to think he met Patrick Stewart or Brent Spiner's characters though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As someone who has the full Frasier on DVD, and has watched it through several times (currently on series 10 of about run 6), I can say :

**No, he doesn't mention it at any point**

As cde mentions in the comments, he also didn't notice the similarity when Patrick Stewart and Brent Spiner were in Frasier as well, so maybe a TOS purest (although he wanted Scott Backula's autograph in Star Mitzvah so who knows).